# Java beginner: Dividing input value in half using a loop but cannot use arrays, built-in sorting routines or any other Java Collections classes

Tags: java, loops, iteration

Java Beginner: I have most of the code complete to solve the problem below but having trouble with my loop section since it is currently dividing one value.  It should continue dividing until it reaches 1.  I'm not sure what's wrong so any assistance is greatly appreciated!!  However, I cannot use arrays, built-in sorting routines or any other Java Collections classes

Problem:
Write a program that will prompt the user for a positive integer: N. The program will repeatedly divide the input in half using a loop, discarding any fractional part, until it becomes 1. The program should print on separate lines:

- the sequence of 'halved' values, one per line
- the number of iterations required
- the value of log2(N)

My code and output when entering a value of 9:

```java
import stdlib.StdIn;
import stdlib.StdOut;

public class DS1hw1b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int countIteration = 0;

        StdOut.println("enter a positive number: ");
        int N = StdIn.readInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            countIteration++;
            if ((N/2) != 1)
                StdOut.println(N/2);

            StdOut.println("number of iterations: " + countIteration);

    //compute log formula
            StdOut.println("log2 of input: " + (Math.log(N)/Math.log(2)));
        }
    }
}
```

```
Output:
enter a positive number: 
9
4
number of iterations: 1
log2 of input: 3.1699250014423126
```

However, I should see is 9, 4, 2, and 1 on separate lines and iteration of 3.

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) { 
will exactly execute once. Doesn't matter what N is. So (as far as I can see) all you need to do is: replace the i <= 1 with i <= 'log formula'

Comment: I'll try that thank you, @Sheradil!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop will only loop once - you initialize `i` with `1`, which adheres to the condition `i<=1`, and stop adhering to it once `i` is incremented.

You're asked to divide `N` by `2` until it becomes `1` - this calls for a `while` loop:

```java
int counter = 0;
while (n > 1) {
    System.out.println(n);
    counter++;
    n /= 2;
}
System.out.println("Number of iterations: " + counter);
```

Comment: I'd replace the condition with N <= 0.

Comment: Thank you @mureinik!  I entered the formula but it repeated the 9 and the iteration count is only 1 and the log value is 0.0                                                                                                                     
int counter = 0;
  while (N > 1) {
   StdOut.println(N);
   counter++;
   N /=2;
  }                                                                                                              
enter a positive number: 
9
9
4
2
number of iterations: 1
log2 of input: 0.0

Comment: @NomadMaker - Change the while loop to while (N <= 0)?  If so, it didn't divide the 9 and it said that I had 9 iterations.

Comment: @blue12 sorry, the number of iterations is of course tracked by `counter`, not `n` - see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik!  I'm a lot closer to the end result but now my log2 formula isn't working.  I'm getting zero when I add an input value of 9.  Also, in order to make sure my input value isn't included in the count, I modified the code as follows but can you help me understand why my log2 formula isn't working now...  while (N > 1) {
   N /= 2;
   countIteration++;
   StdOut.println(N);
  }
  StdOut.println("number of iterations: " + countIteration);
   
 //compute log formula
 StdOut.println("log2 of input: " + (Math.log(N)/Math.log(2)));

Comment: @blue12 note that this solution modifies N as you go. You need to save the original N value to a different variable and calculate the log on it

Comment: @blue12 or, of course, vise-versa - copy N to another value and use it in the loop, and then calculate the log on the original N

Comment: Thank you for your help @Mureinik!!  The code worked.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment to @Murelink.  Here is the updated code but now the log2 formula shows as 0.0 for any number entered.  I thought it would be best to show it this way.  Anyway, I don't understand why it doesn't work since I didn't modify the formula. Thank you all for your help!

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int countIteration = 0;

    StdOut.println("enter a positive number: ");
    int N = StdIn.readInt();

    while (N > 1) {
        N /= 2;
        countIteration++;
        StdOut.println(N);
    }
    StdOut.println("number of iterations: " + countIteration);

//compute log formula
    StdOut.println("log2 of input: " + (Math.log(N)/Math.log(2)));
}
```

}

Comment: I changed the "N" variable in the Math.log() calculation and assigned it a new one.